# Finding all possible integer values of $a,b,c$, given $2$ equations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a^2=bc+1$ and $b^2=ac+1$, how do I find all possible values of $a,b,c$. Assuming $a,b,c$ all are integers?

Comment: Should we assume a, b, c are all integers ?

Comment: Yes.I forgot to include this

Comment: Positive, or can they have any sign?

Comment: They should only satisfy given equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract one equation from the other. Then

$$a^2 - b^2 = bc - ac$$
$$(a + b)(a - b) = -(a - b)c$$
$$(a + b)(a - b) + (a - b)c = 0$$
$$(a - b)(a + b + c) = 0$$

Considering the case where $a = b$: We end up with $a^2 = ac + 1$ so that $a(a - c) = 1$. Since $a, c$ are integers, we only have to consider two cases: $a, a-c = \pm1$.

Considering the case where $a + b + c = 0$: We get $c = -a - b$ so that
$$a^2 = b(-a - b) + 1$$
$$a^2 = -ab - b^2 + 1$$
$$a^2 + b^2 + ab - 1 = 0$$
$$a^2 + ba + b^2 - 1 = 0$$

Viewing this as a quadratic equation in $a$, we know that its discriminant must be nonnegative for real solutions of $a$ to exist. That is, $$b^2 - 4(b^2 -1)\geq0$$
$$-3b^2 + 4 \geq 0$$
$$3b^2 \leq 4$$

and using a similar argument,
$$3a^2 \leq 4$$

Here, we also only have to consider a few cases : namely only $b = 0, \pm 1, a = 0,\pm1$. Note that each possible pair of $a,b$ should be checked against the original equation $a^2 + ab + b^2 -1=0$.

Comment: a^2+b^2+ab+1=2       =     (a+1)(b+1)=2  how you got this plz explain

Comment: @Ayushakj Good Lord, I am ashamed to have made that error. I've edited my answer, do have a look.

Comment: Yiyuan Lee a=b and a+b+c=0 when a=-1 then b=-1 then c should be 2.But when we apply this in equation in question we have 1=-1.plz explain this too.

Comment: It is only required that at least one of $a-b$ or $a + b + c$ is equals to $0$. When we consider the case that $a + b + c =0$, it is possible albeit not necessary for $a = b$. $a,b = -1$ is a possible case for when $a + b + c = 0$, but it is not a solution because it does not satisfy $a^2 + ab + b^2 - 1 = 0$. That said, there are multiple cases but not all are solutions - you'll have ti verify whether or not each case works.

Answer (score 0):

The case when $|a| \leq 1$ or $|b| \leq 1$ can be solved by examination.

Otherwise we have that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. If $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, so is $(-a,-b,-c)$, so we can assume w.l.o.g that  $0< a \leq b$.

Now the first equation implies: $a^2 \geq ac+1$ and the second implies: $ac+1 \geq a^2$. Thus $ac+1=a^2$, which again leads to $|a|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A SCHOOL QUESTION ABOUT THIS POST.

It follows $$ a ^ 2-b ^ 2 = (a-b) (a + b) = (a-b) (- c) $$ When $ a= b$ the integer solutions are only $ (a, b, c) = (\pm 1, \ ± 1,0) $.

When $ a\neq b$ we can simplify the factor $(a-b)$ so we get $$ a + b + c = 0 $$ Therefore we look at the integer points of the plan of equation $ X + Y + Z = 0 $ which have infinitely many of them.

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: The constraints $a + b + c =0$, $a^2 = bc +1$, $a, b, c\in\mathbb{z}^+$ makes it necessary for $3b^2 \leq 4$ as worked out in the solution. From this we can narrow down the possible solutions down to $b = 0, \pm1$, similarly for $a$.